# MediaWiki Extension:SimpleSAMLphp SIMPLESAMLPHP Unregistered redirect_uri when deployed to nginx.ingress.kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, simplesamlphp, mediawiki-extensions

I am having issues getting sso to work with MediaWiki Extension SimpleSAMLphp. I am not sure if it is related to when I access the url: `https:/..../simplesaml/saml2/....` to validate the configuration I get `Unregistered redirect_uri`. I do not receive this error if I type a complete url path, example: `/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php?output=xhtml`. If I click on any of the navigation link on this page, I receive the `Unregistered redirect_uri` error.

```
Bad Request
Unregistered redirect_uri ("https://.../oauth2/callback").
```

I am not sure if this a configuration issue with `SIMPLESAML.PHP`, `SIMPLESAMLPHP` or `nginx`